# SSRS Reports giving me an aggregate error

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting-services-2016

Trying to do some math in SSRS and getting this error.

```
The Value expression for the text box ‘totalboxes3’ has an inner aggregate in an outer aggregate that specifies a dataset scope.  An aggregate that specifies a dataset scope cannot contain other aggregates.
```

I am using the expression:

```
=Sum(Fields!GP_Goal.Value, "Main") / Sum(Sum(Fields!Smartphone_Postpaid.Value) - Sum(Fields!CPE_Postpaid_Only.Value), "Main")
```

Im very new to SSRS so im trying to understand what this is asking me and how to fix it.

ive also tried

```
=Sum(Fields!GP_Goal.Value, "Main") / Sum(Sum(Fields!Smartphone_Postpaid.Value, "Main") - Sum(Fields!CPE_Postpaid_Only.Value, "Main"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
Sum(Sum(Fields!Smartphone_Postpaid.Value) - Sum(Fields!CPE_Postpaid_Only.Value)
```

The outer SUM isn't needed, just subtract the sums and specify the dataset within the sums:

```
=Sum(Fields!GP_Goal.Value, "Main") / (Sum(Fields!Smartphone_Postpaid.Value, "Main") - Sum(Fields!CPE_Postpaid_Only.Value, "Main"))
```